# How to add a legend, banner to shp file exported in PDF

Tags: shapefile, legend, geotools, pdf, getlegendgraphic

I need add a legend, banner and signature to my shp file which is exported in PDF.

My code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put(ShapefileDataStoreFactory.URLP.key, URLs.fileToUrl(new File("D:/var/shp/poli_cercanos.shp")));
    DataStore ds = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
    SimpleFeatureCollection fc = ds.getFeatureSource(ds.getTypeNames()[0]).getFeatures();

MapContent mapContent = new MapContent();
mapContent.setTitle("Quickstart");
Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(fc.getSchema());
Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(fc, style);
mapContent.addLayer(layer);

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int w = 1000;
ReferencedEnvelope bounds = fc.getBounds();
int h = (int) (w * (bounds.getHeight() / bounds.getWidth()));
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

mapContent.getViewport().setMatchingAspectRatio(true);

mapContent.getViewport().setScreenArea(new Rectangle(Math.round(w), Math.round(h)));
mapContent.getViewport().setBounds(bounds);

g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

Rectangle outputArea = new Rectangle(w, h);

GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
LabelCacheImpl labelCache = new LabelCacheImpl();
Map<Object, Object> hints = renderer.getRendererHints();
if (hints == null) {
    hints = new HashMap<>();
}
hints.put(StreamingRenderer.LABEL_CACHE_KEY, labelCache);
renderer.setRendererHints(hints);
renderer.setMapContent(mapContent);
renderer.paint(g2d, outputArea, bounds);
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", baos);

Document document = new Document(PageSize.A2, 20, 20, 20, 20);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:/var/shp/poli_cercanos.pdf"));
document.open();
Image image = Image.getInstance(baos.toByteArray());
document.add(image);
document.close();`
```

My pdf generates the following image from the shp file:

[image: pdf content]

Then the following would be to add a legend and a signature to the image, like this:

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the joys of open source software is the easy you can "borrow" code from another project. [GeoServer](https://geoserver.org) is built using [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) and can produce a legend graphic from a list of layers and styles. Much of the work for that can be found in [BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/master/src/wms/src/main/java/org/geoserver/wms/legendgraphic/BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java).

Once you have one or more legend images it's a simple case of learning how the [`iText`](https://itextpdf.com/en) `PdfWriter` works to lay out the boxes and text elements, probably with a table.